# NodeJS: API not returning response after loop execution is completed although it returns inside the loop

Tags: node.js, rest, express, async-await

In my api creation there is one strange issue I come across that it does not return the final output after successful execution of the nested `forEach` loop.

But it consoles the result inside the loop execution. So, what is the thing that I am missing to get the response ?

repository.ts

```
export class ItemInventoryRepository { 
  public async getItemsData(itemId) {
    try {
      let mainItemList = [];
      var subList;

      let mainQuery = `SELECT table1.id as colOneId,
      FROM table1
      WHERE table1.item_id = ${pool.escape(itemId)} AND option_id = 1`
      let optOneRecords = await pool.query(mainQuery);

      if(optOneRecords.length > 0) {
        
        optOneRecords.forEach(async element => {
          let id = element.colOneId
          let subQuery = `SELECT table1.id as colTwoId,
          FROM table1
          LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.col_two_id
          WHERE table1.item_id = ${pool.escape(itemId)}
          AND option_id = 2
          AND table2.col_one_id = ${id}`
          subList = await pool.query(subQuery);

          await mainItemList.push({
            "colOneId": element.colOneId,
            "subList": subList
          })
          console.log("inSideLoopData :: ", mainItemList)
        });
        console.log("outSideLoopData :: ", mainItemList)
      }
      return mainItemList;
    } catch(error) {
      throw error
    }
  }
}
```

In the below attached terminal screen shot the `outSideLoopData` consoles first and then `inSideLoopData` consoles.
[image]

Postman response where getting the actual response is returning empty array.
[image]

controller.ts

```
public async getItemById(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  try{
    let repository = new ItemInventoryRepository;
    let result = await repository.getItemsData(req.params.id);
    res.status(200).json({data: result})
  } catch(error) {
    next(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: For starters, a `.forEach()` loop is NOT promise-aware and `await` will NOT pause the `.forEach()` loop.  Change that to a regular `for` loop as a first step.  Also, only use `await` on promises.  It does you no good to put `await` on other things that don't return a promise.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, your little reference resolve my problem !!! 
I need to know that how to decide that when to use async-await/promise or use only this normal way that you have suggested currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---- await dosen't work in forEach loop ------

```
optOneRecords.forEach(async element => {
          let id = element.colOneId
          let subQuery = `SELECT table1.id as colTwoId,
          FROM table1
          LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.col_two_id
          WHERE table1.item_id = ${pool.escape(itemId)}
          AND option_id = 2
          AND table2.col_one_id = ${id}`
          subList = await pool.query(subQuery); // await dosen't work in forEach 

          await mainItemList.push({    loop
            "colOneId": element.colOneId,
            "subList": subList
          })
          console.log("inSideLoopData :: ", mainItemList)
        });
```

Pleae use for loop

```
for(const element of optOneRecords){
 let id = element.colOneId
          let subQuery = `SELECT table1.id as colTwoId,
          FROM table1
          LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.col_two_id
          WHERE table1.item_id = ${pool.escape(itemId)}
          AND option_id = 2
          AND table2.col_one_id = ${id}`
          subList = await pool.query(subQuery);

          await mainItemList.push({    // await dosen't work in forEach loop
            "colOneId": element.colOneId,
            "subList": subList
          })
          console.log("inSideLoopData :: ", mainItemList)
}
```

Comment: You can remove the `await` in front of `mainItemList.push()` since that doesn't do anything useful.  The operative `await` here is the `await pool.query()`.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much mate for your efforts to post an answer and ya thanks to @jfriend00 comment to resolve the problem as well.